# Filter for people with an heavily unbalanced question to answer ratio

Tags: feature-request

I find that I'm increasingly uninterested in looking at, or answering, questions from people with an out of balance question to answer ration.

Is there any way of filtering out people like this? I'd happily settle for a manual ignore facility (that ignored any questions from that person).

Comment: @anu - There are those who have the skill to answer and those who need questions answered. Without the latter we wouldn't have many of the good questions answered that people are looking for as the people who answer questions wouldn't ask the questions that those who don't answer do.

Comment: @anu - As I'm the one who opened the "about low rep people" thread: I can fully understand you. It's annoying. I don't know how many Qs I answered where the questioner never came back, didn't mark as solution and similar stuff. Having a filter for this would be perfect.

Comment: @kaiser - it's not really the "one hit" wonders that bother me so much - I think that's inevitable. It's people who have been around long enough and should understand the culture / "responsibilities" of the community that irritate me. And again, that's inevitable - I just shouldn't let it bother me so much!

Comment: @anu - I just wanted to mention another aspect where the system "fails". The problem I see for the whole community is the that it may fade into the direction where the wp.org forums are now: hundreds of unanswered threads; Qs that have half answers because the asker never came back; ...and a small frustraded community that stops answering Qs that come from "outside the circle". (I still hope this won't happen.)

Comment: @kaiser - upvotes are a reasonable indicator of answer quality, I think. What I'm seeing is that most "hit and run" questions from "newbies" are essentially duplicates anyway. I don't think there's any way of preventing people from hitting and running, might be a need for some moderation tools to purge stuff like this. (would also be great if Community stopped bumping questions!).

Comment: @anu - I up- and downvote all the time. Downvoting normally helps preventing that someone invests her/his time into something that's not worth it. And I see that you already started pushing people who got a low accept rate. I guess you can't do more than this: Getting aware of whomes Q you answer (I still answer Qs from the wrong people if the interest me).

Answer (score 1):

Not really. See these discussions:

- [About “low rep” people who ask Qs and don't return for the As.](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/532/about-low-rep-people-who-ask-qs-and-dont-return-for-the-as)
- [Is there any way to ignore a user in SE?](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/300/is-there-any-way-to-ignore-a-user-in-se)

Comment: It's not so much the low rep people, more the few people who ask hundreds of questions and contribute a tiny number of answers. I understand that it's their right to do so, but it still irritates me, especially when I click on one of their questions without realising it. I realise that's petty, but hey, I'm human!

Comment: @anu that aspect is also discussed in first of linked topics